# picturefill.js doesn't serve retina images properly

Tags: javascript, html, retina, picturefill

How can I use `picturefill` to serve retina images?

Currently I'm using the second version of [picturefill.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) which works as a polyfill.

My HTML code is:

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" srcset="http://placehold.it/600x300 2x" alt="Alternative" />
```

**The problem is:** all browsers (except Chrome) are getting the "2x" version, but my screen doesn't support retina.

[I think Chrome is working because this feature was recently implemented.](http://caniuse.com/srcset)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I would test with actual .jpg images you have copied to your server, rather than using placehold.it - you'll just confuse yourself.